# Set-OWAMailboxPolicy parameter OnSendAddinsEnabled fails on Exchange 2016 CU6

Tags: office-js

Exchange 2016 CU6 introduced the OnSend event for Mail Add-ins. To use this feature you need to set the OnSendAddinsEnabled parameter to true using the command Set-OWAMailboxPolicy, but sadly when you try to do this you get the error:

A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OnSendAddinsEnabled'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-OwaMailboxPolicy], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-OwaMailboxPolicy
    + PSComputerName        : XXXXXXX

Get-OWAMailboxPolicy shows the parameter OnSendAddinsEnabled is set to false by default. So it appears it is missing from the Set-OWAMailboxPolicy command even though it is documented for the command https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297989(v=exchg.160).aspx

Does anybody else see the same thing? Is there a way to work around this? You help would be appreciated.

Regards

Duncan

Comment: I have managed to answer this through another source.

You have to perform PrepareAD explicitly when using CU6 to get the newly added entities such as the "Set-OWAMailboxPolicy" parameter "OnSendAddinsEnabled".

Duncan

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to answer this through another source. You have to perform *PrepareAD* explicitly when using *CU6* to get the newly added entities such as the `Set-OWAMailboxPolicy` parameter `OnSendAddinsEnabled`